# Why are my child divs not expanding the parent, even using display: inline-block?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have what seems to be a fairly common problem with my CSS, however - I've been searching Stack and others with no answer in sight. Essentially, my container div is not expanding with it's children. I do have Bootstrap 4 installed, however it's use is very limited.

[image: Visual Div Problem]

The problem is, all of the CSS is basic. It's a Flexbox three column layout, with a header and footer, inside a container:

```
<div class="ui-login" *ngIf="showLoginWindow">
    <div class="header">
        <img src="./../../assets/Logo.png" class="gameLogo">
    </div>
    <div class="h-body">
        <nav class="h-col">…</nav>
        <main class="h-content">…</main>
        <aside class="h-col">…</aside>
    </div>        
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="about">
            <b>About Text</b> <br>
            About Test LLC - 2020
        </div> 
    </div>  
</div>
```

The layout is basic, as is the CSS itself:

```
.ui-login {
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 200;
    border: #34495e solid 2px;
    background: #FFF;

    .h-body {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
    }    

    /* Style the header */
    .header {
        flex: 0 0 100%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 35px;
    }

    .h-content {
        flex: 1;
    }

    .h-col {
        /* 12em is the width of the columns */
        flex: 0 0 12em;
        background: #34495e;
    }    

    /* Style the footer */
    .footer {
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .h-body :nth-child(1) { order: 1; }
    .h-body :nth-child(2) { order: 2; }
    .h-body :nth-child(3) { order: 3; }    
}
```

There is no applied width, height, padding, or margin, and the parent ui-login is also a display: inline-block. None of this seems to be fixing the overflow, when I need the parent to fully contain the layout children. What am I doing wrong?

```css
.ui-login {
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 200;
    border: #34495e solid 2px;
    background: #FFF;

    .h-body {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
    }    

    /* Style the header */
    .header {
        flex: 0 0 100%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 35px;
    }

    .h-content {
        flex: 1;
    }

    .h-col {
        /* 12em is the width of the columns */
        flex: 0 0 12em;
        background: #34495e;
    }    

    /* Style the footer */
    .footer {
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .h-body :nth-child(1) { order: 1; }
    .h-body :nth-child(2) { order: 2; }
    .h-body :nth-child(3) { order: 3; }    
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-login" *ngIf="showLoginWindow">
    <div class="header">
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" class="gameLogo">
    </div>
    <div class="h-body">
        <nav class="h-col">…</nav>
        <main class="h-content">…</main>
        <aside class="h-col">…</aside>
    </div>        
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="about">
            <b>About Text</b> <br>
            About Test LLC - 2020
        </div> 
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the `h-col` class `flex` property.

Comment: Your snippet appears to be working just fine in Chrome.

Comment: Interestingly, it isn't on my end. I do, however, have Bootstrap 4 installed, but I'm only using it for a very limited purpose.

Comment: @random - I need to be able to control the column widths within Flex, in order to keep them equal.